# Selecting records from mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a small search engine project and I need some help with a SQL query.
My table looks like this (example):

```
word        |       docNum
---------------------------
1. blue     |        1
2. pen      |        2
3. pen      |        1
4. green    |        1
5. key      |        2
6. key      |        1
7. car      |        1
```

I would like to look for : blue, pen, green, key  ONLY where their docNum is the same.
So a possible result would be:

```
word        |       docNum
---------------------------
1. blue     |        1
3. pen      |        1
4. green    |        1
6. key      |        1
```

How should the select query look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by the `docnum` and select only those having all 4 words you look for

```
select docnum
from your_table
where word in ('blue','pen','green','key')
group by docnum
having count(distinct word) = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

For above result simply you can use this query :

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE docnum=1 and word IN ('blue','pen','green','key')
```

Comment: in this case `not in` is more suitable

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from yourTable where docnum = 1 and word not in ('car')
```